# How to Add text on CrystalReport using multiple textbox

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I already made parameters on crystalreport for the text.

I research about what code I need to use but everything i found have errors when i modify it for multiple textboxes.

I have 7 textboxes.

I am using vb.net

This is the code I am currently using for date picker of my report.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim StringFormula As String
    StringFormula = "{RejectDB.DateEncoded} >= #" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "# "
    StringFormula &= "AND {RejectDB.DateEncoded} <= #" & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString & "# "
    StringFormula &= "AND {Rejectdb.ProcessReject} <> ('X')"


    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\Reports\SCRAP.rpt"
    CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = StringFormula
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()




End Sub
```

Comment: Dim txtValue As String=TextBox1.Text

Dim myReport As New CrystalReport1

myReport .SetParameterValue("mytextBoxValue", txtValue )

I tried this code but its not working

Comment: Are there any error messages? Please include them in your question.